# How to select the value of a cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, I want to select the cell of the first column.

Heres is my `datagridview.Click` method:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    name = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Currently my name variable is `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You wired up the CellClick event but your code is in the CellContentClick method.  Typo?

Comment: @LarsTech Many thanks that was it it! I had it wired up to the wrong cell click method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CurrentRow may not be set yet, so use the RowIndex property for the event argument.  Try it this way:

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex > -1 && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null) {
    name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
  }
}
```

And just in case, make sure the event is wired up:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.CellClick += dataGridView1_CellClick;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The name variable is still null.  I currently have an error check that does not allow the passed value to be passed to a 'delete object' if it is null, and this is being triggered.

Comment: @user1352057 What if `dataGridView1` is `null` itself

Comment: @user1352057 Noticed I used RowIndex instead of CurrentRow.  Name can't really be null though since it's a string — the cell value is what is null.  What information is in the first column?

Comment: @LarsTech The first column of my database is 'cdTitle' this is set to a 'varchar(50)' type and simply shows a string value that is being displayed from my database. I see what you mean by it not being 'null' as its a string type.

Comment: @Desolator Thanks for your reply. The data from the database is shown on the datagridview. How can i make my dgw not null?

Comment: @user1352057 Are you clicking on a "new row"?  In that case, it would be null because the new row hasn't been committed to the row collection yet.

Comment: @LarsTech I have added a printscreen of the exact row im clicking. No new rows have been added, Im simply trying to store the 'cdTitle' value of the selected row so I can send it to my delete object to delete it from the DB

Comment: @user1352057 I can't repro the problem.  Might be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @LarsTech DoI need to use a different 'cell click method'? Its really weird I have used DGW's before in VB without issue at all.

Comment: @user1352057 Is the event wired up?  Put a stop debugger in your CellClick event, see if it stops there.

Comment: @user1352057 Did you try pressing `Enter` key after adding the value? This could be the reason.

Comment: @LarsTech I have managed to get it to show the correct variable once inthe debugger. Now im back to getting a null value! I must have a mistake somewhere

Comment: @LarsTech I have now added the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      var view = (sender as DataGridView); //<-- notes this
      var currentCellString = view.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Sometimes you need to grab the `sender` object at use that - because it will always be updated.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    object name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    MessageBox.Show(name.ToString() == string.Empty ? "myvalue" : name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This does not get the selected cell value. (unless by chance the selected cell is the cell in the top left corner)

Comment: Besides, there is no ';' at the statement end