# C# retrieve cell value from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I retrieve the information that the user just typed into a cell of a datagridview?  I need to obtain the information that the user entered, process it, and then use it to search for a record in the database.

```
string aux = dataGridView1[3,dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
aux = aux.Substring(0, 7);
dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = mb.pesquisar("select filcod from filme where filtag = " + aux);
```

This code is in an event handler that is fired when the user exits from a cell in the datagridview.  Why am I not retrieving the correct cell value?  How can I obtain the actual value the user typed?

Comment: what else do you need..? do you need us to code the entire thing for you..? what existing code do you have..? or have you not even tried anything initially on your own yet..?

Comment: You'll have to show us the code you have so far and where you're stuck so we can help you.  You can edit your question.

Comment: The user will enter a value in any one cell of the datagridview. Want to get the value in the event "CellLeave" and perform a query in the database based on the value he said.


My Code: 
string aux = dataGridView1[3,dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
aux = aux.Substring(0, 7);
dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value = mb.pesquisar("select filcod from filme where filtag = " + aux);

Comment: That makes it a better question.  I have removed my downvote.  Now, what part is not working?  You have this code in an event handler method, I am guessing, and ... ?

Comment: Criticalfix ... I put this routine in the event of exit of the cell from datagridview. I have a column where the user enters a code and I do a search in the database based on that information. I need is to get the value that was entered in the cell right after the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle this in the [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).  Looking at the documentation at that link, you will see that this method gets passed an event object e.

The object e is a [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) object.  The documentation at the second link shows that the DataGridViewCellEventArgs has RowIndex and ColumnIndex properties.  That is how you find out which cell fired the event, and where to go to get your cell value.

You want to use e.RowIndex because this is from the cell that fired the CellValueChanged event.  It fired precisely because the focus got changed.  That is why the "current" row would be different from e.RowIndex.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143630/how-to-select-the-value-of-a-cell) for an example.